# sum of series $\log2-\sum^{100}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^nn}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The difference of

> $$\log2-\sum^{100}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^nn}$$
>
> $1). $less than Zero
>
> $2). $Greater than  $1$
>
> $3). $less than $\frac{1}{2^{100}101}$
>
> $4). $greater than $\frac{1}{2^{100}101}$

Solution I tried:  we know that $$\log2 = 1-\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+....$$ hence the given series become $$1-\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+.... \;\;\;-  \left (  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{24}+.. \right)$$

I have no idea how to proceed further; please provide a hint.

Thank you

Comment: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^nn}$ is also $\log_e(2)$ but you only want the sum to $100$

Comment: yes the sum is only for 100 terms

Comment: You can google translate [this](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) 'cause there's no such detailed info in English wiki instead of simply $<\frac{1}{2^{100}101}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

By Taylor,

$$\log 2=-\log\left(1-\frac12\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^nn}.$$

Hence the difference is

> $\frac1{101\cdot2^{101}}+\frac1{102\cdot2^{102}}+\frac1{103\cdot2^{103}}\cdots\approx\frac1{101\cdot2^{101}}+\frac1{101\cdot2^{101}}+\frac1{101\cdot2^{103}}=\frac1{101\cdot2^{100}}$.

---

**Addendum (technical):**

If you want to express the exact value, consider the finite sum

$$s(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{x^n}n$$

We have $$s'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{100}x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x}.$$

From this,

$$s\left(\frac12\right)=\int_{x=0}^{1/2}\frac{1-x^{100}}{1-x}dx=\log2-\int_{x=0}^{1/2}\frac{x^{100}}{1-x}=\log2-B\left(\frac12;101,0\right)$$ where $B$ denotes the incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: but we just need 100 terms

Comment: there are some options given let me add them

Comment: @TheStudent: I have given all you need.

Comment: Thankyou @Yves Daoust

Comment: the terms before the $\frac{1}{2^{100}{101}}$ will cancel out

Answer (score 2):

$$\log2-\sum^{100}_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^nn} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=101}\frac{1}{2^nn}$$

You can put bounds on this:

$$\frac{1}{2^{101} 101} \lt \sum^{\infty}_{n=101}\frac{1}{2^nn} \lt \sum^{\infty}_{n=101}\frac{1}{2^n 101}= \frac{1}{2^{100} 101}$$

so between about $3.9 \times 10^{-33}$ and about $7.9 \times 10^{-33}$; in fact about $7.7 \times 10^{-33}$